# How to convert from string to string constant in struct?

Tags: c#

So I have this struct:

```
public struct PurchaseOrderStatus {
    public const string Open = "Open", Received = "Received";
}
```

How do I convert if I have the following:

```
    string status = "Open";
```

To:

```
    PurchaseOrderStatus.Open;
```

By Convert, I mean, how do I do this:

```
    PurchaseOrderStatus POS;
    String status = "Open";
    POS = status;
```

Comment: Define "convert", they both are the string "Open"...

Comment: I assume that you mean the equivilant of an enum.Parse("Open") for a struct?  Not sure that there is one without using reflection...I would refactor your stuct to an enum if you can.

Comment: Yea, that is what I mean.  I couldn't use enum because enum only store integer and I need to store string.

Comment: You say "i need to store string", just curious why?  You can convert an enum to string as well.  i.e. MyEnum.Open.ToString() will yield the string "Open"

Comment: Some enum have space in them.  This would not work.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu For that you'd need to use Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using "smart enums" here:

```
public sealed class PurchaseOrderStatus
{
    public static readonly PurchaseOrderStatus Open =
        new PurchaseOrderStatus("Open");
    public static readonly PurchaseOrderStatus Received =
        new PurchaseOrderStatus("Received");

    private readonly string text;
    public string Text { get { return value; } }

    private PurchaseOrderStatus(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

You can store arbitrary information here, including text which *wouldn't* be valid identifiers (so long as it doesn't change, of course). It's still strongly typed (unlike your strings) and you can give other behaviour to it. You can even create subclasses if you remove the `sealed` modifier and add the subclasses as *nested* classes so they still have access to the private constructor.

Oh, and there's a *genuinely* limited set of values (the ones you've defined and `null`) unlike with regular enums.

The only downside is that you can't switch on it.

Comment: If one is suitibly motivated you can also add onto this by adding 1) an intelligent `Equals` method 2) implicit conversion to string 3) explicit conversion *from* string 4) `operator ==` overload 5) static enumeration of all possible values.  Also consider whether you want it to be a class or a struct; either could be justified.